# Unlock feature using rewarded videos in chartboost (App rejection)

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, chartboost

I'd just like some clarification. This is a term & condition from Apple for submitting apps:

"Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected"

Does this mean if I use "Rewarded Videos" from Chartboost to unlock features in my game I will have the app rejected? I know it sounds like this is what they mean, but it seems a lot of chartboost advertising apps are doing this (I think).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple's review policy, not programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think they will reject your app as there are other games that use Video Ads to unlock in-game items. Have a look at this game [Hellrider](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hellrider/id973429655?mt=8) on itunes Appstore. All the content in this game can be unlocked just by watching rewarded videos. no in-apps.